# What is this window switcher (screenshot) running on Windows Vista and how do I disable it?

Tags: windows-vista, window-manager

I'm diagnosing a problem on a friend's Windows Vista machine.  Basically it has this intermittent issue where without any user input, it seems to activate some kind of window switcher/tiler program which zooms out all the windows.  Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image: An unknown window switcher program]

It's possible this is just the Windows Vista switcher (I don't use Vista myself) and I'm just not recognizing it.  Whether it's a built in thing or some add-on, it's quite frustrating that it seems to activate all on its own.  There doesn't seem to be any icons in the toolbar and I've tried digging through the start menu and can't find what program it is.  I've also done a Google Image search and can't seem to identify a program that looks just like this (grey bar/white text across the middle of each window), so I'm stuck.

Does anyone know what program this is and how to disable it?

Comment: We don't have enough information to identify it.  The good news its not the default of Windows Vista.  Boot to a minimal start-up configuration to see if it happens.

Comment: Try 'uninstall a program' in control panel and look for it there

Comment: a task swither or alternate shell might not show up easily. you could look with "AutoRuns", while it would still be a guessing game as to what it is, with autoruns you could temporarily disable and boot and hope.  Autoruns also gives that ability to ignore deemed to be Windows and MS specific items, which can help with the diagnosis.

Comment: look if a tool called **Switcher** is installed: http://insentient.net/

Comment: I'll check out autoruns.  I don't believe it's Switcher -- I did look for this and it doesn't seem to be installed, plus the grey band across the middle of the windows doesn't seem to be a Switcher aesthetic.